# how to extract a number from a line in a file where the number is connected to other charchter in python?

Tags: python

i am new to python and trying to write a simple code that reads lines from a given file,
i am having a problem extracting a hexadecimal number from a line :
for example i have the following file lines:

```
# Program start at address 0, after reset.
I@0x00000000

D@0x000032A0
```

i want to extract the two hexadecimal numbers (they represent the start of instruction and data addresses)
i wrote the following code and the method "get_start" is supposed to extract the first integer which is zero but instead i get the following output:
  `['0', '00000000']`

my code :

```
import sys
import re

class Memory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.progStart=0
        self.data_start=0

    def get_start(self, line):
        patterns = [r'\d+']
        for p in patterns:
            match = re.findall(p, line)
            print(match)
            return match



    def sim_mem_reset(self, memFileName):
        with open(memFileName, 'r+') as fileName:
            for line in fileName:
                if line[0] == '#' or len(line.strip()) == 0:
                    continue
                if line[0] == 'I' and line[1] == '@':
                    self.progStart = self.get_start(line)   
                    print(self.progStart)
                if line[0] == 'D' and line[1] == '@':



# main
memory = Memory()
file_name = sys.argv[1]
print("Loading memory image file:", file_name)
memory.sim_mem_reset(file_name)
```

Comment: why i wrote octal i will never know lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regexes. It's very simple to solve using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [the `int` class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#int):

```
def get_start(self, line):
    '''
    Assumes `line` looks like: I@0x01234567
    '''
    return int(line.strip()[2:], 16)
```

Comment: This only works as long as the there are always just two character in front, though. But it solves the example. EDIT: Hah, you commented. :-)

Comment: can i ask a basic question

Comment: i just noticed that i changed the value of progStart (parameter that belongs to the class) inside the sim_mem_reset method .. can i do such a thing ? or i only have to change the value of such parameter outside of the class?

Comment: Of course you can. If you were able to change that only from outside the class, there would be no encapsulation whatsoever, but this lets your class manage some hidden internal state while exposing only some methods to the user. (Well, Python doesn't _really_ have encapsulation, like C++, but that's as close as it gets)

Answer (score 1):

The number is hexadecimal, and you can extract it by using `str.split()`:

```
s = 'I@0x00000000'
num = int(s.split('@')[1], 16)
```

This will extract the hexadecimal number after the '@' character.